# how to use r to filter data that has multiple condition

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have this set of data, where firms receives subsidy in different years, and I want to find the firms (ID) that never received any subsidy, i.e. sub = 0 in year 2010-2021.

I tried to use `filter(firms$sub==0)`, but i don't know how to find the ID that show all zero during year 2010-2021.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(firms)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(firms, 20))`.

Answer (score 0):

We may group by 'ID', and `filter` only those having `all` the `sub` values are 0 within the `year` range of 2010 to 2021 and extract the `distinct` ID

```
library(dplyr)
firms %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    filter(all(sub[year %in% 2010:2021] ==0, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    distinct(ID)
```